# How to stop contents of div shrinking as screen size changes?

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a portfolio website like this now.

[Website Link](https://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/2622?siteId=7e761c3c-729b-4d4e-9dc3-a8242c486f56&metaSiteId=3f62d478-a066-43ee-98e6-3e48600ff893&originUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%3Fcriteria%3DEngineering%2BPortfolio%26page%3D3&tpClick=view_button)

Typically when the width of the screen size is less than half of the full width for the website, its content starts to be hidden instead of shrinking. Mine on the other hand, keeps shrinking.

How do I do that with CSS?
It's what I've done so far. I'm using sass and React.js.

App.scss

```
$main-container-height: 87vh;
$navbar-height: 13vh;

/* Navbar style */
.navbar {
  height: $navbar-height;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  .name {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 1.5rem;

    a {
      color: black;
      font-size: 25px;
      margin: 0 0 0 0.5rem;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .box {
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      background-color: blue;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }

  .nav-list {
    a {
      color: black;
      margin: 0 1.5rem;
    }

    a:hover {
      color: #519df9;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
}

/* Homepage Style */

.main-box {
  height: $main-container-height;
  min-width: 50%;

  .left-main-box {
    height: $main-container-height;
    width: 40vw;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #e8c9c9;
  }

  .right-main-box {
    display: inline-block;
    height: $main-container-height;
    width: 60vw;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

HomeMain.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CenterBox from "./CenterBox";
import Footer from "./Footer";

export class HomeMain extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-box">
        <div className="left-main-box">left</div>

        <div className="right-main-box">right</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: by default nothin shrinks and nothing is hidden. If something shrinks, that's because of your code. So please show your code. Besides of that you may want to look into media queries.

Comment: ok, what have you tried so far on this and what is it you are having issue with ? Please share a reproducible code for us to help. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I just updated it. Thanks

Comment: [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) might be helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you expect since I can't replicate the problem: decreasing screen width on the link you provided has no shrinking effect for me in Firefox.

That being said: 
I recommend that you do you layout for small screens first as it is way easier to do this way rather than the other.
In order to do that you can use [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) along with [media queries.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

For example, you can achieve that using grid-template-areas property, and change this layout using a media query.
Once your template is ok, you can style elements within containers with flex for alignment etc.

Don't forget to use min-width and max-width when using responsive units.

something like that (you get the idea)

```
/* mobile */
.main-box{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "nav"
    "content"
    "footer";
}

/* desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
  .main-box{
    grid-template-areas:
      "header header header"
      "nav nav nav"
      "leftbox content rightbox"
      "footer footer footer";
    }
```

More on [grid](https://cssgridgarden.com/) and [flex](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) if you want to practice.